# Fetch JSON data using Authorization header in D3 v5

Tags: d3.js, authorization, fetch-api

I am working on some charts in d3.js v5.8.2 and I want to load JSON data that I get from an API request which needs an authorization header. I tried something like:

```
d3.json('url')
  .header("Authorization", "Bearer 7tsBVpsiYT")
  .get(function(error, data) {
    // callback
    console.log(data);
  });
```

I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: d3.json(...).header is not a function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since D3 v5 uses the [Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) as a replacement for the `XMLHttpRequest` which was used by prior versions the API for `d3.json()` needed to be changed a bit. From the docs:

> [*#*](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#json) d3.**json**(*input*[, *init*]) <>
>
> Fetches the JSON file at the specified *input* URL. If *init* is specified, it is passed along to the underlying call to [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method); see [RequestInit](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit) for allowed fields.

You now have to pass the `Authorization` header via the `RequestInit` object which is passed as the optional second argument to `d3.json()`. As Mike Bostock explains in his basic demo [*Fetch with Basic Auth*](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/fetch-with-basic-auth) this can be done using the native Fetch API:

```
fetch("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd", {
  headers: new Headers({
    "Authorization": `Basic ${base64.encode(`${login}:${password}`)}`
  }),
}).then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.status);
  return response.json();
});
```

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/src/json.js) of `d3.json()` one notices that above code is basically equivalent to what D3 does internally while executing `d3.json`. Thus, the code can be rewritten as:

```
d3.json("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd", {
  headers: new Headers({
    "Authorization": `Basic ${base64.encode(`${login}:${password}`)}`
  }),
}).then(json => { /* do something */ });
```